# Call microsoft graph with existing token received from web app

Tags: java, azure

I'm modifying a backend server to consume tokens provided by azure ad, the portal web app opens the microsoft pop up to login, and once the user is logged in it calls the api I'm working on.
The web app is registered in azure ad.
The server validates the token and I wanr to call the microsoft graph to obtain user information that is not in the token.

Can in someway I use the token that is received from the web app to call the graph api? Or do I have to obtain another token to call the graph api? In this second case, how to obtain a second token?
The server uses spring boot and java.
The only data I have is the token passed from the portal.
The azure ad application has access to profiles.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to call Graph from the portal or from the API?

Comment: I wanted to retrieve some data from the graph, from the API, however I  learned how to include the information in the token's body, therefore it was not necessary to connect to the microsoft graph.

Comment: Not sure about Java, but it's a widely used case, and I used it personally in my asp.net web app and asp.net web api. User login to web app, get a token from Microsoft identity, and then call the web api using this token. Then, the api will accept your call because of that token, and then use this token to call MS Graph. If you want I can share the .Net detail and you convert to java

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created a **`Server Application`** and Exposed an API:

[image]

I added API permissions in the **`Client Application`** like below:

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using parameters like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:api://5c4cc2c2-66e7-4ccf-b7ac-f9a9d16bfd3b/test.read User.Read.All
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token the **aud** is  **`api://AppID`** like below:

[image]

When **I tried to call Graph API using the above generated access token**, I got the error like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID
```

[image]

> **Note** that : By using one access token, it is not possible to call two APIs. The **aud** to call Graph API must be `https://graph.microsoft.com` and the **aud** to call Web API must be  `api://AppID`.

So, **generate another access token to call Graph API** like below:

I generated the **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:User.Read.All
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token the **aud** is `https://graph.microsoft.com` like below:

[image]

When I tried to make a call using Graph API using the above access token, **I got the results successfully like below**:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID
```

[image]